# Serialize an ASP.NET MVC model in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I have a model like this

```
public class Category : BaseFieldsTables
{
        public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public Category Parent { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

i want to serialize the model to json and this is my controller

```
    var categories =
            _efCategory.List().ToList().
                ToList().
                Select(x => new {id = x.Id, title = x.Name, children = x.Parent});

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(categories, Formatting.Indented,
                                                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                                                        {
                                                            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
                                                        });

        return Json(output.Replace, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but i get this result

```
    "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"$id\": \"1\",\r\n    \"id\": 1,\r\n    \"title\": \"News\",\r\n    \"children\": null\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"$id\": \"2\",\r\n    \"id\": 2,\r\n    \"title\": \"2012\",\r\n    \"children\":
 {\r\n      \"$id\": \"3\",\r\n      \"Categories\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"$id\":
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. All you are seeing is the escaped version of your string (probably directly in Visual Studio). `\r\n` is the equivalent of a newline character and `\"` is just a means to escape the `"`. Outputted, this should appear as normal.

Comment: but i want use this for tree and i get this error Uncaught Invalid data type for [
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "id": 2,
    "title": "News",
    "children": null
  },

Comment: That means that you are parsing the JSON incorrectly. You are going to have to post more code... the JSON itself is correct.

Comment: i don't know why like this    "$id": "13",
    "id": 12,

Comment: You are going to have to post more code and be more specific.

Comment: var categories = new CategoryMapper().MappModelToCollectionOfViewModel(_efCategory.List())
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new { id = x.Id, title = x.Name, children = x.Parent});

   string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(categories, Formatting.Indented,
                                               new JsonSerializerSettings
                                                {
                                                 PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
                                      })
   return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Your code appears to be very complex, and contains several of your own methods that you have not posted the code for. In addition you haven't posted the context in which this code is found... If you want to know why id = 13 you need to look further than just the single line of code that returns the result. I suggest you take a better look at your overall code, try and refine the question a bit more and then perhaps ask again. The issue has nothing to do with the slashes as indicated in the original question.